# Problemas con un Select usando un chosen y un boton colapsado en Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, laravel-5, laravel

Hola estoy queriendo implementar un formulario de busqueda avanzada en el cual se abre a partir de un boton colapsado en bootstrap. Aqui implemento un panel con un select.

Implemento un plugin llamado [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html) que le mejora la estetica al select y demas. la es que me sucede esto
[image]

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
Busqueda Avanzada
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
 <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top:2px">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('provincia_id','Provincia') !!}
            {!! Form::select('provincia_id',$provincias,null,['class'=>'form-control select-provincia','placeholder'=>'Provincia del evento...','required']) !!}
    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
@section('js')
<script>

    $('.select-provincia').chosen({
        placeholder_text:'Seleccione una Categoria',
    });

</script>   
@endsection
```

Si desactivo el plugin, se ve bien (como un select normal), activado pero fuera del collapsed tambien funciona bien.

Alguna idea donde puede estar el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta fue bastante sencilla aunque no tan logica como esperaba. De algun modo tiene un problema con size el collapsed

A prueba y error, buscando algo entre los parametros de chosen, encontre q se le puede modificar el tamaño. Probe y efectivamente crece en porcentaje como cualquier css.

```
$('.select-provincia').chosen({
    width: "100%"
});
```

Al poner 100% se ajusta al tamaño del contenedor